# create an other data if elements are same

Tags: r

I have two data sets A and B (shown below), and wanted to create third data set called C, based on this condition: If elements of A and B are Same (or matched) then its should be C (if not macthed then that element should be NA/missing).

A

```
2 5 9 3
5 3 2 1
2 1 1 3
```

B

```
2 7 9 3
5 3 6 1
2 2 2 3
```

expected C should look like

```
2 NA 9 3
5 3 NA 1
2 NA NA 3
```

BOTH data have same dimensions, any suggestion please?

Comment: `C <- B ; C[B!=A] <- NA` ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for both data frame and matrix.

If `A` and `B` are data frames:

```
C <- A
C[C != B] <- NA
C
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  2 NA  9  3
# 2  5  3 NA  1
# 3  2 NA NA  3
```

If `A` and `B` are matrix:

```
A <- as.matrix(A)
B <- as.matrix(B)

C <- A
C[C != B] <- NA
C
#      V1 V2 V3 V4
# [1,]  2 NA  9  3
# [2,]  5  3 NA  1
# [3,]  2 NA NA  3
```

**DATA**

```
A <- read.table(text = "2 5 9 3
5 3 2 1
2 1 1 3",
                header = FALSE)

B <- read.table(text = "2 7 9 3
5 3 6 1
                2 2 2 3",
                header = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Cath What do you mean? How can I improve my post?

Comment: @Cath I see. I was not seeing your comment when I was working on my post. With reproducible examples to create the data and examples on both data frame and matrix, I hope my posts at least serve a good use case. What do you mean "put it as wiki"?

Comment: @Cath Thanks for your explanation. I have done that.

Answer (score 3):

```
`is.na<-`(A,!A==B)
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2 NA  9  3
2  5  3 NA  1
3  2 NA NA  3
```

Comment: Or `is.na(A) <- !A == B`.